# Laravel how to add minute to time

Tags: laravel

I want to make estimate time when user will come. I have 2 variable to save, open and closed time of the store.

```
$openTime = Carbon::parse($open);
$closedTime = Carbon::parse($closed);
```

i can get the duration between 2 variable. And i can get duration for each person who come.

```
$Duration =  $startTime->diffInSeconds($endTime); 
$perpersonDuration = gmdate("H:i:s", $Duration/$quota);
```

The question is how to add $perpersonduration to time. In this case i want to add $perpersonduration with $opentime. So it will be like $opentime + $perpersonduration.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

In Carbon there is a method called [`addMinutes()`](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub) and you can pass the number of minutes as you won't like this

```
$openTime = Carbon::now(); // 02:00:00

$closeTime = Carbon::parse($openTime)->addMinutes(30); // 02:30:00
```

Comment: but, the perpersonduration can be hours to sir. So its depends on the result.

Comment: you could use `addHours`